# Connecting dual 27" Apple thunderbolt displays to PC

Tags: display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I have two of the Apple 27" thunderbolt displays, and a Dell M3800 laptop running Windows 7. The laptop has a thunderbolt port, and can run one of the Apple displays just fine. When I daisy chain another Apple display, the display on the far end of the chain works, but the one on the near end of the chain goes dark.

Is there any way to connect two of these displays to this computer?

Note: The ports on both displays, and the PC are thunderbolt, not displayport.

Answer (score 1):

The Thunderbolt Display does not support daisy-chaining Mini-DisplayPort.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154

I did see a report somewhere that computers that can drive two monitors over were able to get around this be inserting another Thunderbolt peripheral in the middle. I.e., Mac > Thunderbolt Display > Thunderbolt RAID > Mini DisplayPort monitor.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the display is using thunderbolt as the interface, and not mini-displayport. The port on the computer is capable of both, but that monitor will not function in a displayport-only connector.

Comment: Correct, it uses (and requires) a Thunderbolt port. Thunderbolt is multi-protocol and I believe the monitors are driven by DisplayPort being mapped in the protocol. For whatever reason, you cannot run a second Thunderbolt Display from the first. That's by design. Someone who understands the details of the Thunderbolt controller might be able to explain that. And explain why some have been able to run a second display by inserting another Thunderbolt peripheral into the chain.

Answer (score -1):

This [product](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=a8228351) may help. However, it costs much!

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please describe what it is pointing to. Of special interest in this case would be your practical experience with the product.